# How to get proper reference to refreshing method in one class(JPanel), so it can be called from method in another class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jmenu

I have JFrame bulid like this :

```
public class AplicationGui extends JFrame{

  public AplicationGui() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    panel = new RaportPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    Menu menu =new Menu();
    setJMenuBar(menu);
  }


}
```

RaportPanel have a method for refreshing it's content.
In menu I have action listener which call JDialog - FooDialog like this :

```
fooDialog=new FooDialog();
fooDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(FooDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
fooDialog.setModalityType(FooDialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
fooDialog.setVisible(true);
```

I want FooDialog to call a refreshing method  from RaportPanel, when  FooDialog is closing. How to get proper reference to that refreshing method so it can be called from closing method in FooDialog ? Maybe I should rebuild all so it will work better?I quite new to Java and I don't know how to solve it.  I pretty sure there is a easy way to do this. I will be grateful for any suggestions and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with a listener pattern. 
Impl. an interface for listeners of closing dialog.
Let the class opening a dialog impl. this interface and register him to the dialog. 
Provide a register listener method in your dialog class, where you save given listeners. When dialog closes inform all your listeners about it.

This is a general approach. Tipicly this is already included in Swing API, which I'm not aware in the moment.

Here a small example using your class names ;)

```
public interface DialogCloseListener {
  public void dialogClosed();
}

public class RaportPanel implements DialogCloseListener {
  ...

  fooDialog=new FooDialog();
  fooDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(FooDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  fooDialog.setModalityType(FooDialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
  fooDialog.setVisible(true);
  fooDialog.addDialogCloseListener(this);   // <-- Register the listener

  ...

  public void dialogClosed() {
    // Do something when dialog closed!
  }
}

public class FooDialog {
  List<DialogCloseListener> listeners = new ArrayList();

  public void addDialogCloseListener(DialogCloseListener listener) {
    if (!listeners.contains(listener)) {
      listeners.add(listener);
    }
  }

  public void onClose() {   // Pseudo code, look up Dialog class reference for correct callback
    for (DialogCloseListener listener : listeners) {
      listener.dialogClosed();
    }
  }
}
```